# ambiguity of complexity analysis of for loop containing O(1) operations

Tags: performance, for-loop, queue, time-complexity, analytics

I have been doing a program in which we are popping the elements of the queue until the queue becomes empty.The thing is that we know that time complexity of pop operation is O(1) and while it is running in a loop.So we can say we have a loop that is running O(1) operations for the time till the queue is not empty.
Suppose q has some number of elements say 1,2,3,4,5,6

```
   while(!q->empty())
   {
   cout<<q->front()<<" ";
   q->pop();
   }
```

And I have read on geeksforgeeks that if loop is running for a constant number of times and is running O(1) operations in it..then that loop is considered to have time complexity of O(1).

This was said like that:

A loop or recursion that runs a constant number of times is also considered as O(1). For example the following loop is O(1).

```
    // Here c is a constant   
    for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {  
    // some O(1) expressions
    }
```

So the while loop for queue also has O(1) or O(n) or I am mistaken . Plz help me to clear my ambiguity.

The link for geeksforgeeks article is:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

Comment: *"if loop is running for a constant number of times"* - what makes you think this loop is running for a constant number of times?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it this way: if the number of steps in your algorithm does not depend on the size of your data `n` - it has a constant complexity.

If you have to do "something" once for each of your `n` - you have a linear complexity, or `O(n)`. That's the case with your queue example.